# Match and Conditional Formatting from Matrix Table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am looking for some decent help with my matrix table, and is there a good or best approach to properly match dependent instances in certain matrix using drop downs.

This picture represents my **matrix table** (Picture 1):

[image]

As you can see there are a lot of instances, but horizontally and vertically they got the same number of "headers". Those **"1`s"** are representing not compatibility in my case but lets call it simply **"match"**. That is on one sheet that is gonna be populated with some new values from time to time.

On another sheet which is actually sheet for showing the data and their compatibility possibilities is equipped with drop downs. There you got **"Groups (Group1, Group2...)"** in a sense of main parts and **"dependent groups (AA1, BB2..)"** as small components that are part of main parts. To avoid misunderstanding here you have explanations, I used for the sake of this example fictional values:

**Groups aka. Main Parts**

**Dependent groups aka. components**

As you can see beneath, is my fictional table but exactly the same concept as I should use in my real case.

***I PUT AN EXPLANATION IN THE PICTURE 2 SO YOU CAN FOLLOW ALONG AND SEE EXACTLY WHERE/WHAT I DID!***

What I used firstly there are *=match* functions, one for vertical position (A3) and one for horizontal (B4). This boolean row is done using *=or(index)* but reffering to the match positions as you can see. And from there I should use true/false for coloring my group boxes in a case compatibility is possible - thats all the science.

So, my question is if there is another approach to this problem? As you can see I have 3 different rows of functions at one place, or imagine if I will have more "groups" that can rise in many more rows and calculations.

**Picture 2**

[image]

**EDITED:**

This is screenshot of the original sheet, I just hid some rows that were with Infos that is reason the number is not consistent. As you can see it is almost the same as dummy example I provided above. Underneath every "box" you got three rows of calculations as I mentioned before. The two times number "2" that you see here is the position of some value that I found using *=match function*, one is for horizontal and another for vertical lookup. In this case it is model type, 070FX is position 2, 100FX is 3 and 200FX is 4th position in the matrix table, and so on for all the other groups. And those groups (Model, Endpoint, Gas sensor...) are defined separately on another sheet where I had to make unique list and dependent list so I can reference those to my drop down list.

[image]

**EDIT Nr 4!**  So this formula I used for `true/false`:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(('0359-matrix'!$A$2:$A$101=F10)*(('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$B$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$C$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$D$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$E$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$F$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$G$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$H$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$I$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$J$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$K$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$L$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$M$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$N$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$O$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$P$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$Q$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=F13)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=G13)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=H13)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=I13)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=J13))*'0359-matrix'!$B$2:$CW$101)>0
```

**I copied only last part, or when it starts from second row..Because it is too long to write whole funciton - it cuts down automatically.**

```
('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$Q$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$B$13)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$C$13)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$D$13)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$E$13)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$F$13))*'0359-matrix'!$B$2:$CW$101)>0
```

But on marked cells I am getting the same results: B22 - F22 has the same as B21 - F21 (boolean) what shouldnt be like that but to follow color, green is False, it has to be something with an array reference. 
[image]

Comment: I think you should narrow the problem down to a bit more observable.

Comment: @TheGridLock  Check edited version.

Comment: @Mirza I think I finally understood what you are trying. You want to know if all the selected parts (yellow fields) are compatible to each other by checking the matrix in picture one (which tells us which are compatible and which are not)? If that is what you want have a look at my answer.

Comment: In wich cell exactly is the formula you show? Which is the exact formula in B22 in your last edit? Make sure it refers to the values in line 13 and not to the values in line 10! Note you cannot just copy it one line down from row 21 to 22, you need to adjust the formula then! • To get around the `_` issue change the last part of your formula `*'0359-matrix'!$B$2:$CW$101)>0` into `*('0359-matrix'!$B$2:$CW$101=1))>0`. Then only `1` will be counted as incompatible any any other value will be treated as `0`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ  The formula that I wrote starts in B21 and then B22! I edited so you can see last formula so in cell F22! 

Ahaa, so thats how I should "avoid" gaps. Alright will check it!

Comment: @Mirza Actually the beginning matters `=SUMPRODUCT(('0359-matrix'!$A$2:$A$101=F10)*…` here `F10` is the range that changes in each cells if you copy the formula. This is actually the only part of the formula that changes. The rest will be always the same. So if the formula has a `F10` here it should be the formula in F21. Check it.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Look, formula is working good when I have =SUMPRODUCT(('0359-matrix'!$A$2:$A$101=B10), and yeah that part changes only (C10, D10...), BUT, when I wanna copy it in a second row (for instance B13, C13,D13...) then it is a trouble, I cant reference properly - do you understand now??? It is a bit awkward example.

Comment: If you copy it to the second row you need to adjust the formula in B22 so that it points to `B13` in the beginning it cannot do that automatically. Then you can copy the formula from B22 to C22:F22. How does the beginning of tho formula in B22 look like?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ  =SUMPRODUCT(('0359-matrix'!$A$2:$A$101=B13)*(('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$B$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$C$10)

But it doesnt give properly...so B13, C13, D13 should be the first part right?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ  It works actually, at home now I tried and i dont see a problem anymore. Maybe cuz of Office365 at home and Office2016 in the Company.   I should say Big thanks to you man!! This was such a challenge, and I learn a lot how to use and reference such a examples, simply amazing!!!

Comment: Well, good to hear. Btw I am using Office 2019 and it should definitly not make any difference which of the mentioned versions you use. They should all be able to do it. I assume you made some little mistake at some point that caused an issue and we just didn't find it. The longer the formula gets the more likely you make a mistake • But the idea of the approach is actually pretty clear and works (if no mistakes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the following. A1 to E5 is the matrix that shows which pieces are incompatible (=1). The others have to be empty or `0`.

[image]

In cell I8 I used the following formula (and copied it down up to I11):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5=H8)*(($B$1:$E$1=$H$8)+($B$1:$E$1=$H$9)+($B$1:$E$1=$H$10)+($B$1:$E$1=$H$11))*$B$2:$E$5)
```

The formula result shows you the amount of incompatibilities a part has. Eg `AA1` has one incompatibility with `BB2` but `BB2` is incompatible with 2 `AA1` and `CC3`.

To get the `TRUE`/`FALSE` use the same formula and append `>0`: like `=SUMPRODUCT(…)>0`

For any additinonal "group" (Model, Endpoint, …) you need to add another `+($B$1:$E$1=$H$12)` where `$B$1:$E$1` points to your matrix data and `$H$12` to your selected group value.

Overview of the formula ranges:
 [image]

Note that this kind of calculation can only tell the amount of incompatibilites a part has but not the names of the parts that are incompatible.

---

#### Edited horizontal version

[image]

Formula in the selected cell is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$5=G8)*(($B$1:$E$1=$G$8)+($B$1:$E$1=$H$8)+($B$1:$E$1=$I$8)+($B$1:$E$1=$J$8))*$B$2:$E$5)
```

you can pull it to the right.

Comment: @Peh  (sorry cant spell it better, missing ALT signs) :D   this was good idea, similar I also found BUT: =SUMPRODUCT((_0359_matrix[_]=B10)*((_0359_matrix[#Headers]=$B$10)+(_0359_matrix[#Headers]=$C$10))*_0359_matrix[[070FX]:[ZF1]])

I tried just one file to see if It is fine but I am getting #value!  Is it problems with referencing my columns aka. tables?? 

Second question, you did example here vertically (taking H column as a ref.) is it possible to reference if it is vertically?? So, Model,Endpoint and so on that are separated per Column with drop downs instead Row groupping??

Comment: @Mirza It does not work properly with formatted table references (because you cannot pull down the formula then because it get's destroyed). I recommend to use the normal references to cells like I did `$A$2:$A$5` (make sure you get the `$` right, some have them some don't!). • And of course you can do it horizontally. Just move the cells around (see my edit).

Comment: @Peh   what am I doing wrong here: =SUMPRODUCT(('0359-matrix'!$A$2:$A$101=B10)*(('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$B$10)+('0359-matrix'!$B$1:$CW$1=$C$10))*'0359-matrix'!$B$2:$CW$101)

it drops me always #values  I just wanted to test for 2 instances and it doesnt work at all.  What about this true/false? you mean to put it whole at the end? )>0 ?

Comment: @Mirza Are there only `1` and `0` or epmty cells? if there is something else (especially text) in the matrix it does not work (see my very first sentence of the answer)!

Comment: this "1" is text format actually..sorry I didnt notice it from beginning. The guys that are uploading it originally made it like that....  so they are text values!!

Comment: @Peh  look, is there a way to have those "_" instead of 0 or empty?? This is what  I get as a usual .csv file.

Comment: @Peh I edited my post so you can see my formula now!! I fixed it actually to try without "_" in my matrix and it worked, BUT, what if I got  drop downs in a second row ? I tried to modify a bit this formula and to adapt references but gives me same instances for the first columns (B, C, D, E, F). I will upload party pic so you can see better.

Comment: @Peh  It is me again, is there a way to calculate those " _ " like 0 or something in this formula??? I was struggling yesterday with example, why is not working and so on...but I just remembered that I manually removed " _ " from my matrix. And unfortunately guys here are still uploading it " 1 " and " _ ".   And I am getting error in my formula, so the same formula from up but just made errors because of " _ ". Any idea how to deal with them? They are all text format.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Mirza As I said already: To get around the `_` issue change the last part of your formula `*'0359-matrix'!$B$2:$CW$101)>0` into `*('0359-matrix'!$B$2:$CW$101=1))>0`. Then only `1` will be counted as incompatible any any other value will be treated as `0`. Note that the `1` needs to be a numeric value not a text. Otherwise it fails. If the `1` are text you must use `*('0359-matrix'!$B$2:$CW$101="1"))>0`

Comment: @Peh Ohh...damn I missed that =1))  completely...sorry about spamming. Is there a way tp combine =value or =isnumber function inside to make it work automatically?

Comment: Not that difficult to test or? `*(VALUE('0359-matrix'!$B$2:$CW$101)=1))>0`

Comment: it sttill gives...#value!   I tried that before I saw your comm....

Comment: @Mirza checkout `*(NOT(ISERROR(1/VALUE('0359-matrix'!$B$2:$CW$101)=1))))>0` then.

Comment: @PeH  Damn man, this works flawlessly!!! Simply amazing! Is there something you dont know how to solve???  :/  CAn you just tell me what is meaning of (1/value)? I am not that expert in Excel..

Comment: @Mirza That was just a trick not to trigger on empty cells. I used `1/value()` because `value()` of an empty cell is `0`. Then `1/0` causes an error (you cannot devide by `0`), so empty cells are not treated as number.